# How to use geom_errorbar to indicate standard error in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table

Lets say I have a data table called dt

```
| group | value |
| -     | -     |
| a     | 1     |
| b     | 2     |
| a     | 3     |
| b     | 4     |
| a     | 5     |
```

And I already have my Jittered Strip Plot and I need to indicate the standard error in ggplot2
by using geom_error. Since there are two varibles a and b in column group. How do I specify the group when I calculate mean() and sd() in the geom_error function

Do I have to create another table to store mean and sd for my dataset?

Answer (score 3):

I think Rui's method is sensible; it is often better to calculate the statistics beforehand and plot them. However, you *can* do it all from raw data using summary functions in ggplot:

```r
ggplot(dt, aes(group, value, group = group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.1), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.data = mean_cl_boot, width = 0.2) +
  geom_point(size = 4, stat = "summary", fun = mean, shape = 3) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(2)

dt <- data.frame(group = sample(c("a", "b"), 20, TRUE),
                 value = sample(100, 20, TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi Allen! I just found out that I can use stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se.geom="errorbar") to get the standard error.

Comment: Yes, you can either use stat_summary(geom = "errorbar") or geom_errorbar(stat = "summary") as in my answer - they produce the same output. You can use `mean_se` or `mean_cl` or `mean_cl_boot` for fun.data in either case depending on your preference for how the standard error is calculated.

Comment: What differences do they have for calculating standard error?

Comment: `mean_cl_boot` uses a non-parametric bootstrap method, so you don't need to assume your data are normally distributed @SimonLi

Answer (score 2):

The way to do it is to compute the summary statistics before the plot.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(data.table)
})

setDT(dt)
dt[, c("mean", "sd") := list(mean(value), sd(value)), by = group]

ggplot(dt, aes(group, value)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

The following is an object of class `"data.frame"`. It is coerced to `"data.table"` in the code above.

```
dt <-
structure(list(group = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a"), value = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, Rui! Thank you for your answer. But what I trying to do is to indicate standard error in my plots which generate from my raw dataset. How should I able to do this?

Comment: @SimonLi I am not understanding, like I say in the answer, if you want to plot summary statistics, compute them beforehand, then plot. This is also true for standard errors. To show error bars you need means and sd's, so compute them and plot.

Comment: Oh im so sorry I misunderstood your answer. I will try this!!

Comment: Hi Rui When I tried to create mean and sd column for the data by using ur code i got an error like this "supplied 2 columns to be assigned 3 items" how should i fix it?

Comment: @SimonLi With the posted data my code works, if it's giving you an error then can you update the question with a reproducible example?